# What's the meaning of `declare -i` in bash? Does it restrict variable to only numbers?

Tags: bash, integer, declare

Can anyone explain purpose of `declare -i` in bash? Is it for security so that you don't do string operations on numbers?

If I assign a string-number to a variable, I can already do mathematical functions on it, so what's the point of `declare -i`?

Comment: Have a [look here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html).

Comment: Thanks RedX. Thanks again to meet comment length requirements.

Comment: Bash variables are not `typed`, but `declare -i` allows you to `'hint'` to the shell that is should expect to find an integer value in the variable which in turn allows arithmetic operations on that variable without raising an error (e.g. `((foo++))` ), etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare -i` sets the `integer` attribute for a name. It doesn't affect the *use* of the variable at all, only assignments *to* the variable. The right-hand side of an assignment is treated as if it were an arithmetic expression, so that `foo=3+5`, `foo="3 + 5"`, and `foo=$((3 + 5))` are identical.

In my opinion, it's not very useful, as it provides little benefit over an explicit arithmetic expression. You save 3 characters, `"..."` vs. `$((...))`, (unless you can safely leave the expression unquoted). Worse, it obscures the semantics of the assignment at the point it is actually made. (That is, when you seen an assignment, you need to look around to see if the `integer` attribute was set on the name before you know what the assignment actually does.)